# How to implement table paginator in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm starting in angular 6 and I have some problem to implement a table paginator.

First of all, I would like to see the paginator working in my view. After this, I will try to implement the table with paginator.

I'm looking for one example in Angular Material documentation available at this page below:

https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/overview

When I try to run the application I get the error below

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'length' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-paginator'.
```

I Don't know what the problem is, because I had imported all modules according to the example from angular material, but I think that is missing some import that I need to do. I sincerely do not know.
Could you please help me understand what's happening? Thank you for help

follow my code below:

```
app.module.ts

import { AngularDraggableModule } from 'angular2-draggable';
import { DraggableAreaService } from './core/tardis/remote- control/service/draggable-area.service';
import {
  MatAutocompleteModule,
  MatBadgeModule,
  MatBottomSheetModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatButtonToggleModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatCheckboxModule,
  MatChipsModule,
  MatDatepickerModule,
  MatDialogModule,
  MatDividerModule,
  MatExpansionModule,
  MatGridListModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatListModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatNativeDateModule,
  MatPaginatorModule,
  MatProgressBarModule,
  MatProgressSpinnerModule,
  MatRadioModule,
  MatRippleModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatSidenavModule,
  MatSliderModule,
  MatSlideToggleModule,
  MatSnackBarModule,
  MatSortModule,
  MatStepperModule,
  MatTableModule,
  MatTabsModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatTooltipModule,
  MatTreeModule,
  } from '@angular/material';

export const MaterialModules = [
 MatAutocompleteModule,
 MatBadgeModule,
 MatBottomSheetModule,
 MatButtonModule,
 MatButtonToggleModule,
 MatCardModule,
 MatCheckboxModule,
 MatChipsModule,
 MatDatepickerModule,
 MatDialogModule,
 MatDividerModule,
 MatExpansionModule,
 MatGridListModule,
 MatIconModule,
 MatInputModule,
 MatListModule,
 MatMenuModule,
 MatNativeDateModule,
 MatPaginatorModule,
 MatProgressBarModule,
 MatProgressSpinnerModule,
 MatRadioModule,
 MatRippleModule,
 MatSelectModule,
 MatSidenavModule,
 MatSliderModule,
 MatSlideToggleModule,
 MatSnackBarModule,
 MatSortModule,
 MatStepperModule,
 MatTableModule,
 MatTabsModule,
 MatToolbarModule,
 MatTooltipModule,
 MatTreeModule,
];

@NgModule({
 declarations: [
   AppComponent,
   AdminComponent,
   AuthComponent,
   BreadcrumbsComponent,
   SigninComponent,
],
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  HttpClientModule,
  BrowserAnimationsModule,
  AppRoutingModule,
  SharedModule,
  AngularDraggableModule,
  ...MaterialModules
 ],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

code.html

```
<mat-paginator [length]="100"
       [pageSize]="10"
      [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">
</mat-paginator>
```

Comment: At the moment, you're adding `MaterialModules` as an array within an array. Try changing it to `...MaterialModules` within the `imports`

Comment: I do it in imports, but I got the same error. does not working. :(

Comment: How have you done it? Can you edit your question to show it please?

Comment: Sorry. Done! You can see the update

Comment: Hmmm... It seems to work when I create a StackBlitz (even before making that change)... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fpixq4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts Are you able to create a fork that reproduces your issue?

Comment: I found the error. I was importing the wrong file. I have the app.module.ts and I have the module from component that I'm would like to use the paginator. So I was importing wrong. it's correct now.

Answer (score 0):

In my project I have some module.

app.module.ts
device.location.module.ts

So, I would like that the paginator was created in device.location.html
and the module from this html is device.location.model.ts

So, I was importing the modules in app.module.ts.
I change the import for device.location.module.ts and it's working. now :)

thanks